# Is it possible to have different names for an app on Android market and on the phone?

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

I have a cool name for my app that shows up when installed on a phone but I would like to have a different name for it on the Android market.

My app uses Facebook's graph API so I want to have something like "AppName for Facebook" so that it can get more Facebook keyword hits on the market but I don't actually want the full name to show up on the phone's home screen (I just want it to show as "AppName"). Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title in the Market is not the same title as on the phone. You can set the title in the Market as you wish.

Go to the developers console, click on your app, then in the details area you can set your title.

The title on the phone is of course set in the AndroidManifest.xml in the application tag

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **yes**.
When you upload your application, you get to fill in a 'title'-field on your market site.
The name displayed on the phones is the one you specify in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like all the others stated, it **is** possible, as you can enter a custom name when publishing the app (some apps even have stuff like "Sale" in their title).

However, I would **not recommend** using the word Facebook in your title

1. It won't impact your rank very much, as your app has only a few downloads
2. *Your app will be removed* because Facebook doesn't like apps that have their name in their title and does everything to remove these apps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was worried about that but I saw that a lot of other apps append "Facebook" to the end of their titles. I'm not sure if they have some sort of agreement with Facebook. Some examples: FriendCaster for Facebook, RollCall Check-in for Facebook, Friends Checker for Facebook et al

Not sure how to interpret those. I will try to dig up some info on this. Appreciate the help.